# How to add to a variable when addition is in an for-loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

This is a problem from [codewars](https://www.codewars.com/kata/5287e858c6b5a9678200083c/train/javascript). Heres my code.

```
function narcissistic(value) {
var total = 0
var valLength = value.length
const digit = [...`${value}`];
for(var i = 0; i < value.length; i++){
  total += Math.pow(value.length , digit)
}
  if(total == value){ return true

  } else {
    return false
  }
}
```

The problem I'm having is I don't why when I do `total += value.length * digit[i]` it isn't adding to `total`. Any ideas?

Comment: where is this `if` function you refer to in the title?

Comment: What value are you passing to the function?

Comment: why are you `var valLength = value.length` ... then use value.length everywhere and ignore valLength?

Comment: @Bravo sry fixed it

Comment: @Andy Its from a website where it already has tests. Sry if I didn't clarify that

Comment: @Bravo I noticed it but was too busy trying to figure out my other problem lol

Comment: Yes, but to help you we need to know what the input is _in your question_.

Comment: @Andy A Narcissistic Number is a positive number which is the sum of its own digits, each raised to the power of the number of digits in a given base. In this Kata, we will restrict ourselves to decimal (base 10).

For example, take 153 (3 digits), which is narcisstic:

    1^3 + 5^3 + 3^3 = 1 + 125 + 27 = 153
and 1652 (4 digits), which isn't:

    1^4 + 6^4 + 5^4 + 2^4 = 1 + 1296 + 625 + 16 = 1938

Comment: The Challenge:

Your code must return true or false depending upon whether the given number is a Narcissistic number in base 10.

Error checking for text strings or other invalid inputs is not required, only valid positive non-zero integers will be passed into the function.

Comment: those are the instructions from codewars

Comment: try the components separately in the browser console or in node to test them. For instance, what happens if you set a variable to a number and try to access length? `var value = 7`, `value.length`. By trying each step separately you will understand what's happening at each step and why the function is not giving the expected output

Comment: When i run the code with return total, it return 0. Which Isn't right. I think its cause total +=     Math.pow(value.length, digits) isn't working as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:
You need to convert the function parameters into an array with different values and then calculate the power of each number and then add to the total.
Also, try to use let instead of var as it is better for block-level scope.

```js
function narcissistic(value) {
  let total = 0;
  const digit = [...`${value}`];
  for (let i = 0; i < digit.length; i++) {
    total += Math.pow(digit[i], digit.length);
  }
    if(total === value) { 
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
  
  console.log(narcissistic(153));
  console.log(narcissistic(432));
```

Answer (score 0):

This function can return you the required value

```
function narcissistic(value) {
    const stringValue = [...`${value}`];
    const len = stringValue.length;
    const sum = stringValue.reduce((prev, current) => {
        return prev + Math.pow(parseInt(current, 10), len);
    }, 0)
    return `${value}` === sum.toString();
}
```